# Why are some Windows DLL's loaded and some aren't?

Tags: windows, dll, load

So looking at procmon and filtering for DLL's, I've noticed that some DLL's go through the process of

1)"CreateFile"

2)"ReadFile" (or "QueryBasicInformation")

3)"CloseFile"

while other DLL's actually get loaded and executed

1)"CreateFileMapping"

2)"LoadImage"

3)"CloseFile"

My question is, why are some DLL's loaded and executed as I assumed they should be, and some are only read and not loaded at all? How can you tell which DLL's are for loading and which are just for reading?

Comment: Resources libraries ?

Comment: The procmon `CreateFile` operation could be for an internal (fast) create for `NtQueryAttributesFile`, or from `NtOpenFile` prior to `NtCreateSection`. The same applies to other operations. Examine the stack trace to get a more complete picture of the context of an operation.

Comment: We get a clearer picture by stepping into `LoadLibraryExW` calls using a debugger. `LoadLibraryExW` normally calls the NT loader function `LdrLoadDll`, which finds and loads a DLL *as a module*. But for loading as a data or image resource, if the DLL is not already loaded, it finds it via `LdrGetDllPath` and `RtlDosSearchPath_Ustr`, and then maps it via `CreateFileW`, `NtCreateSection`, and `NtMapViewOfSection`.